# Alterar a nomenclatura da tabela migrations do Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

Estou criando uma aplicação que deverá ser escalável e para isso foi feito um escopo completo das tabelas, relacionamentos e afins. Nesse escopo, eu utilizo a tabela `migrations` que o Laravel 5.1 trata para cada implementação do banco de dados. Existe alguma forma de eu alterar a nomenclatura da tabela **migrations**  para algo "embrasileirado" (ex: Versionamento, Migracao, Versao), para assim ficar mais legível o código para qualquer um na equipe?

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro? Sou novato em questão a laravel, estou vindo do CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No arquivo `config/database.php`, onde há um `array` de configuração, você deverá alterar a linha que contem o seguinte:

```
'migrations' => 'migrations',
```

Para o que você deseja, como:

```
'migrations' => 'migracoes',
```

Veja na linha 101:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.1.11/config/database.php

Comment: Direto ao ponto assim que eu gosto! Valeu irmão!!!